# Could not cast value of type 'FIRDatabaseReference' (0x108f4d170) to 'NSString' (0x10a4f24a8)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database reference that I want to change to a String and then to a URL type.

```
let database = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid!)/pathToImage")

let string = database as! String  // **Code Crashes here
let url = URL (string: string)!

func setImage() {
  ImageService.downloadImage(withURL: url) { image in
    self.currentProfileImage.image = image
   }
}

setImage()
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
let database = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(did!)/pathToImage")
```

isn't a type of a direct url string , it's a refrence to your image , you need to single listen to it

```
database.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 
  let str = snapshot.value as! String
  print(str)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be confused about how the Realtime Database SDK works.  If you have a database reference, and you want the value of that location of the database, it's not going to work to simply convert that reference to a string.  You have to query the database at that location, use a callback to receive the data, then get the string out of the snapshot that was delivered to the callback.

I suggest going over the documentation for how to perform database queries in order to understand how it works.  In particular, pay attention to the section called [read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once).  Your code will look more like this:

```
let ref = ref.child("path/to/string")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let value = snapshot.value as? String
  // use the value here
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```